# WhatsApp Web is active even after putting Mac to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, whatsapp.app

I got a notification messages on my phone saying "WhatsApp Web is currently active" even when my MacBook is supposed to sleep and not check for messages. Power Nap is not switched on and I have set Do Not Disturb to On when the display is sleeping.

I am concerned about the impact on the battery life of my MacBook. I am not sure if the WhatsApp Web app just prevents the laptop from sleeping, or if the MacBook is in some form of modern standby similar to Power Nap.

I am using the official WhatsApp for desktop application on macOS Mojave:

- [WhatsApp Desktop](https://apps.apple.com/app/whatsapp-desktop/id1147396723)

One option to solve this is to quit the application every time before putting the laptop to sleep. Is there any other workaround to fix this issue?

Note: Here's a screenshot of the Energy Saver settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your energy saving settings? Also, you could turn on Log out after certain minutes in Security and privacy.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue on WhatsApp Web. Haven't found a solution that works though.

Answer (score 1):

> WhatsApp Web is currently active

This is just an information notification that you receive on your mobile device, some time after you log into WhatsApp Web or WhatsApp desktop app (which is just a wrapper over the web app).

You can safely ignore this and rest assured, the app is **not** running on your MacBook while it is asleep.

Comment: Can you provide any source for this? When I use web.whatsapp on a browser, I received the notification precisely whenever I switched to the tab with web.whatsapp. Even with the app, whenever I open the app/un-minimize it, I receive the notification. The notification I receive is not a delayed one since I receive it even if the laptop has been asleep for 1-2 hours. (The notification also has a timestamp, so I am not confusing it with an old one)

Comment: Actually, I agree with Ansh, Mac still keeps network connections active. MacOS Sleep != Windows Sleep. I would so love to understand how to put MacOS to sleep in the same way I can with Windows, where the hard drive simply freezes and there is no more connectivity to anything, until turned on again and resumes. For MAC, sleep is just turning the screen off ffs